# Dataweave 2.0 - Cannot coerce String to LocalDateTime

Tags: mule, dataweave, string-to-datetime

I get a CSV file with data that I transform to application/java.

One of the fields (Creation_Date) is a DateTime field that I get as String because the output field is a string type.

**Input field:** Creation_Date (*String*) - **Example**: 2019-03-02 07:00:00.000

**Output field:** CreatedDate (*String*) - **Example**: 2019-03-02 08:00:00.000

I use that code in my Dataweave 2.0 transformation because I want to add one hour more to the input datetime:

```
CreatedDate: payload.Creation_date as LocalDateFormat {format: "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss+01:00"}
```

But it returns an error:

```
 Cannot coerce a String to a Localdatetime, caused by CreatedDate
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add or modify parts of the data such as adding hours you should convert to LocalDateTime and then use a Period to add a specific Period of time to the datetime. Also need to as milliseconds to format based on your expected input/output. Try this, but change pretendPayload to payload for your example:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var pretendPayload = {Creation_date: "2019-03-02 07:00:00.000"}

type LocalDateFormat = LocalDateTime { format: "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS" }
---
{
    CreatedDate: (pretendPayload.Creation_date as LocalDateFormat + |PT1H|) as String{format: "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS" }
}
```

Info on Period here: https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.1/dataweave-types#dw_type_dates_period

Answer (score 0):

You can use the now() in dataweave 2.0. Check the URL: https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.1/dw-core-functions-now.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Seems gtx911 is more concerned with how to format dates as strings than getting the current date.